# Laravel: Directiva Blade no funciona

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Quizás exista una mejor manera de hacer lo siguiente pero quisiera un poco de retoralimentación para saber que es lo que está mal.
Estoy tratando de crear una directiva de blade la cual pueda hacer formato de pesos o dolares, me refiero a que si le damos una cantidad como 35000 esta directiva se encargará de formatearla de la siguiente manera 35,000, para que sea más legible, el problema es que no estoy obteniendo los resultados que esperaba, este es el código en el AppServiceProvider:

```
Blade::directive('formatodinero', function ($precio) {
        $precio = strrev($precio);
        $tamanio = strlen($precio);
        $nuevoPrecio = "";
        $j = -1;

        for($i = $tamanio; $i > 0; $i--){

            if($j % 3 == 0){
                $nuevoPrecio .= ',';

            }

            $nuevoPrecio .= $precio[$i-1];
            $j++;
        }

        return "<?php echo ($nuevoPrecio) ?>";

    });
```

Y la manera en la que llamo la directiva desde mi vista es esta:

```
@formatodinero($propiedad->precio_venta)
```

En lugar de imprimir el resultado formateado con comas estoy obteniendo la cadena que paso a la directiva en si.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intento hacerlo directamente desde un [mutador en laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu puedo ayudar con cosas que yo he implementado, primero hay una funcion de PHP que hace lo que estas que queriendo lograr, [number_format](http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php):

Te propongo dos soluciones, diferentes a la directiva.

**1** Directamente en blade podes imprimir lo siguiente:

```
{{ number_format($propiedad->precio_venta, 2, ',', '.') }}
```

**2** Crear un mutator en el modelo del objeto que tenga el precio de venta

```
public function getPrecioVentaAttribute($value)
{
    return number_format($value, 2, ',', '.');
}
```

Con lo cual cuando en tu blade pones algo como lo siguiente:

```
{{ $propiedad->precio_venta }}
```

te devuelve automaticamente el valor formateado.

---

Por otro lado para ayudarte con la directiva que estas queriendo crear, te diria que nos muestres con un dd() que valor tiene la variable $precio en la directiva para poder ver lo que esta pasando y lo pongas en tu pregunta:

```
dd($precio);
```

Comment: Estaba complicando las cosas con las directivas, la segunda solución del mutador funcionó a la perfección, tendré que investigar más acerca de eso, muchas gracias!